# How would a new planet join an intergalactic united nations and economy?

Tags: economy, government, interspecies-relations, interstellar-travel

Wordy title, heh. Say a new planet gains access to spacefaring capabilities comparable to that of what exists in some galaxy or galactic cluster. And in that galaxy or cluster, there's a body akin to the U.N. How then does this new planet A) Come into economic relations with the other members of that body and B) join that body itself? And which comes first, and what timeframe would you be looking at (assuming galactic and Intergalactic travel closer to the time of flying around Earth a few times)?

This seems fairly complicated, and will depend on anything unique the new planet has in terms of resources (in my story's case, mass use of a kind of magic) among other things. So I thought I'd ask!

Comment: The new planet will most likely begin by trading with one or more members of the Intergalactic Unites Nations and Economy. In our own Earthling history long-distance trade precedes the United Nations Organization by many millennia; and even now, membership of the U.N.O. is not at all a requirement for international trade -- for example, the Republic of China is a major participant in international trade although it's not allowed to be a member of the U.N.O. After a while, the new planet may initiate the process of joining the I.U.N.E., according to the (sadly unspecified) rules of the I.U.N.E.

Comment: Why would the U.N want to let in a new nation that may not have the capacity to defend itself on the galactic stage yet, much less come to the support of other nations?

Comment: @Muuski because it cannot defend itself seems like a very good reason, that is part of why the UN exists.

Comment: What FTL method is in use? Unless space travel is incredibly cheap and easy (EX some sort of teleportation, easily constructible wormholes), trade is probably not going to occur. Transporting things either at relativistic STL speeds or using proposed FTL systems (Alcubierre Drives, wormholes) is incredibly expensive, taking hundreds of times the energy used by all of human civilization to move an aircraft carrier sized ship to just low relativistic speeds, for instance, and resources are so abundant within each solar system that trade would be impossible without easy, cheap FTL.

Comment: Right now on Earth, there are tribes in remote places (such as the rain-forests of Brazil or Papua New Guinea) which have had little or no contact with the outside world.  They will find that they are living on land which has already been claimed by others.  This is one scenario which would likely be similar on the interstellar scale.
 So, it seems likely that this "new" planet would find itself already in the territory of another civilization, and subject to at least some of its laws.  They would have no direct representation in the "U.N."; at least not at first.

Comment: Of course, that won't apply if the technological levels of all civilizations (including the "new" planet) are similar.

Comment: There will probably be some forms to fill out.

Comment: I'd like to see some clarification on the "magic", and expanded info on the dominant species of the planet, specifically temperament. If they are humanoid, but not human, they might act in a way completely different to us, as seen in numerous sci-fi media. If FTL travel was suddenly made possible on earth, unless tightly restricted, our planet would erupt like a crushed anthill. Within a decade we'd have vast swathes of the galaxy explored and well-established celestial mining and manufacturing. We'd quickly make contact with a galactic governing body, or find ourselves in interstellar war

Comment: I think you have an interesting basis for a query, but you'll need to give us more detail. Is this the First Galactic Empire, the United Federation of Planets, the Borg? What are we dealing with?

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I had a health scare yesterday.
@RichardSmith It's basically a SW style DTL where ships slip into some parallel dimension, so it's not a hard system who's workings are compatible with IRL FTL proposals. In my story, it's intended to be relatively inexpensive for trade purposes.

Comment: @cowlinator The technological levels will be near enough the same.

Comment: @DreadedEntity They're humanoids with a chi-like magical energy, and the discovered FTL tech is all in the hands of the government at the start, not a widely available thing.

Comment: @elemtilas It's very much intended to be like the UFP.

Comment: @AlexP Yes, those are the kinds of comparisons I was wondering about. Since in this case, the planet gains FTL capable tech in a relatively short span of time and was otherwise physically isolated from & incapable of interacting with other planets, how does this change how getting into economic relations happens in comparison to IRL? If it's too much for a comment here (understandable), do you know of any discussions about this topic as applies to real life?

Comment: There are many relatively well-known science-fiction stories which touch a new world's initial contact with an established interstellar organization; either as a major plot point, or as a side note. *It's your story*, what happens and how it happens is your choice. *Ranks of Bronze* and *The Excalibur Alternative* offer one (militaristic) option. *Childhood's End* offers a rather terrifying trans-humanistic option. The much loved *Star Trek* offers several options, ranging from the idealistic Vulcans to the belligerent Romulans. Really, I don't see how you can hope to get the one true answer.

Comment: Okay, so UFP like. This might be a good opportunity for you to edit your query!

Comment: One thing you still might want to keep in mind is that basic commodities are still not likely to be traded. If you manufacture on planets and lift them into space, that is a very energy expensive process. Currently, it costs SpaceX $2,720 to lift a single kilogram into orbit, and even space elevators aren't cheap ( calculated on wikipedia to cost $220 per kilogram, assuming current power beaming efficiencies and electricity costs). If you manufacture in space, you will need to have extensive infrastructure there, and have to spend lots of resources on fuel or pushing lasers.

Comment: IDK what happend to the font. And even if interstellar travel in your setting does not require Jovian mass wormholes or warp drives requiring several times the entire modern world's energy budget to operate, it will still likely cost something. Food: no. Most metals: no. Basic clothing and furniture: no. Luxury goods and ultra-advanced electronics: maybe. Also consider the sheer age of the universe. It is 13.8 billion years old, and though there were no stars early on and not much metal after that, there is still a vast amount of time in which life could have formed.

Comment: It is ludicrously improbable that all life would develop within roughly the same time interval, and even a gap of 1000 years between civilizations arising could create major power gaps. If humanity experiences 1% annual population growth yearly, which would be doable if we are capable of expanding with space habitats and FTL and develop life extension technology, we will number 160 trillion in just 1,000 years, which is a blink of an eye in astronomical timelines.

Comment: In the most likely scenario, one species is going to arise first, and with cheap FTL and a head start of at least a few million years, they will use their first mover advantage to colonize the galaxy and beyond before anyone else has even evolved beyond pond scum. They will have such a massive lead on technology, infrastructure, etc. that almost no one else will even be relevant. Also consider the vast amounts of resources available in just one solar system.

Comment: The asteroid belt probably contains orders of magnitude more metal than has ever been mined in human history, and it is just 3% of the mass of Earth's moon, and there are also the Near Earth asteroids, the Jovian asteroids, the Jovian moons, the Kuiper Belt, the Oort Cloud, Mercury, Venus, Mars, etc, etc, etc, all of which are much nearer at hand than distant aliens. And even when that is exhausted, you can use powerful magnets or lasers to extract material from the Sun itself and fuse hydrogen into heavier elements into particle accelerators. But this is just some stuff to think about.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that travel and trade is possible. Then the usual reason to trade is [comparative advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_advantage).

- Planet A has pretty exhausted mines for iron ore (because they've been producing steel tablespoons for a long time) and excellent factories for tablespoons (same reason). Say that it takes 10 man-days to mine the ore for a shipment of tablespoons, and 10 man-days to turn the ore into finished products.
- Planet B has better iron ore mines (because they haven't been producing steel tablespoons quite as long) and worse factories for tablespoons (same reason). Say it takes 5 man-days to mine the ore for a shipment of tablespoons, and 15 man-days to turn the ore into finished products.

Under these conditions, planet A and planet B would each need 20 man-days to mine and produce one shipment of tablespoons. If they work together, mining on B and manufacturing on A, it takes only 15 man-days. So if transport costs are minor in comparison to wages and factory infrastructure, an *interstellar* company could undercut purely *local* ones by one quarter.

(Where that *advantage* ends up depends on the negotiating strengths. Consumers may pay less, miners may earn more, manufacturers might make more profits, customs might take a part, and merchants want their profits. Or some mix of all of those.)

Similar calculations can be done if A is better than B for **both** products.

- Planet A has well-established shipyards. It takes 100 man-years to build a starship and 10 man-years to build a shuttlecraft.
- Planet B has less developed shipyards. It takes 1,000 man-years to build a starship (ten times the worktime because of the complicated FTL drives) and 50 man-years to build a shuttlecraft (no FTL, but still difficult for an underdeveloped world).

If a shipping line on B needs a starship and a shuttle, they could spend 1,050 man-years to build them locally. Or they build 11 shuttles in 550 man-years, sell 10 of them to A, and buy their starship on A (exchange rate on A: 10 shuttles per starship).

If a shipping line on A needs 20 starships and 10 shuttles, They could spend 2,200 man-years to build them locally. Or they spend 2,100 man-years to build 21 starships, sell one of them to B, and buy 20 shuttles from B (exchange rate on B: 20 shuttles per starship).

Answer (score 1):

I think that a lot depends on the state of the current members of your space-UN.
If those members are post-scarcity-societies, the new planet will quickly gain access to the UN. 
Yet, trade will come first. As soon contact is possible it will be made. And provided that it is possible for private companies to make contact and have the physical possibilities of trading, they will do so much quicker than a planetary government will be able to act. And even after they are, there might be treaties and agreements to be negotiated. In the meantime, any private company that is capable to will have established trading links.

Now, if the other members of your space-UN are not post-scarcity societies, but capitalistic systems, then they will do anything they can to exploit that fledgling spacefarer to the best of their capabilities.
I assume that as a member of space-UN, the civilization of this new planet would be granted certain rights that non-members have not, so the rich and powerful will do anything in their power to prevent those rights to be granted as long as it's more profitable for them that the new civilization is unprotected.

Answer (score -3):

## Interstellar trade is impossible

## Space is big.

I’m sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but interstellar trade is impossible. The travel time between even relatively close worlds is obscenely high compared to human life spans. Traveling out and back to the nearest star from Sol is 8 years if you go at lightspeed, which matter cannot do. The best *theoretical* time is estimated at 20 years for a single round trip. The economy is unsustainable for any pair of exchangeable commodities.

If you try to set up any coherent government, you also fail. The lag time in communications alone make law making and rule enforcement impossible. Any delegate to a galactic UN is committing social suicide... for almost all delegates, everyone they know will be dead by the time they get home. How can they negotiate on behalf of a planet when their knowledge of home world is centuries out of date? They cannot.

Space Is big. Really big. You aren’t thinking big enough. Space is big enough to kill all our stories. It’s a one-way trip, not an ecology. The only thing worth trading is stories and data, and that will flow freely and at a far faster rate than matter can move.

Any attempt to introduce FTL travel always introduces time travel and causality violations. You cannot have one without the other. http://www.physicsmatt.com/blog/2016/8/25/why-ftl-implies-time-travel

Your story idea is dead because Space Is Big.

I’m sorry.

Comment: FTL travel is an accepted trope in science fiction. This isn't tagged *reality check*.

Comment: This doen't answer the question and ignores the assumptions in the question.

Comment: This is a frame challenge answer. The OP suggests FTL travel but does not deal with the time travel implications thereof. Given everything in the question, the answer is, "It is impossible."

Comment: *"Interstellar trade is impossible"*, oh really? Because, of course, our current understanding of physics is the one and only final truth, and there can be no question about it. The speed of light is the ultimate barrier, and it is useless for man to even try to think about breaking it.

Comment: @AlexP you’re welcome to find a way around it. I hope we do. But if you do, you will enable time travel. That’s a simple matter of geometry.

Comment: Oh no, not necessarily. There a way to enable FTL travel without enabling time travel as a side effect. The simplest one is to postulate that all FTL travel takes place with respect of a fixed and privileged frame of reference. (Which has the incovenient that as far as we know all inertial frames of reference are strictly equivalent... But at least it avoids the time travel issue.)

Comment: @AlexP regardless, no option detailing how FTL was going to be handled (all the gorey details) was included with the OP. My argument against any “Star Trek/Star Wars” scenario being even remotely viable stands unless solutions are offered because those solutions affect the answer rather dramatically.